# Upload and Display Image with Location coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c#, wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I want to upload an Image on Map and the image should contain some coordinates that when uploaded should display in the same location as the coordinates, I am working on C# and Wpf.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for displaying a local image file in an ArcGIS Runtime app:

- You can display a [georeferenced](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/data/imagery/overview-of-georeferencing.htm) raster in a [RasterLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/sample-code/raster-layer-file/), which works in either MapView (2D) or SceneView (3D). Local raster files require a Standard license.
- You can create [ImageFrames](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.ImageFrame.html) from your raster files, with either embedded or separately-provided georeferencing information, and [display them one at a time in an ImageOverlay](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/sample-code/animate-images-with-image-overlay/). This only works in SceneView (3D) and requires a Lite license.
- You can create [KmlGroundOverlays](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Ogc.KmlGroundOverlay.html) from your image files and geographic envelopes, and [present any number of them](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/sample-code/edit-kml-ground-overlay/) in a KmlLayer. This works in either MapView and SceneView. You can display existing KML files with a Lite license, but you will need Standard license to programmatically create/edit/save KML documents.